# How to control release versions with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, release-management

When releasing desktop apps we usually rename the binary to contain the version number. This version isn't stored anywhere else but in the file name.

- What are the advantages of storing the version number elsewhere? (ex. In the project properties, in the setup script, etc)
- How to automate the version number update process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old article but still has validity so might be worthwhile reading. You can manage versioning in VS in the projects properties its quite simple to do.

[The Build Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817676.aspx)

Comment: it began to work when I removed `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]`

Comment: This is an old article I only linked it because it highlights the reasons for using versioning in your applications. If you go to "Project > Project Properties" then select the publish tab you will see the version tools. Also The "Application" tab click the "Assembly Information" button.